# How to avoid the constructor documentation in jsDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a class declaring only static methods, as in

```
class Foo {

  /**
  * This method does nothing
  */
  static doNothing() {
  }
}
```

However, `jsDoc` generates the documentation also for the undeclared constructor of the class, so that, from the documentation, the class appears to be able to generate instances, which is not what it is intended to do.

If I declare the conctructor to explicitely tell `jsDoc` to ignore it, as in

```
class Foo {

  /**
  * @ignore
  */
  constructor() {
  }

  /**
  * This method does nothing
  */
  static doNothing() {
  }
}
```

jsDoc ignores the whole class.

Perhaps, a class of only static methods should not be considered a class.
It makes sense to me, so that, I am reconsidering the design of my library.
However, I would be courious to know if someone has faced such a problem and how he has managed to solve it.

Comment: Add a private constructor?

Comment: @knittl same result: the whole class is ignored.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: yes, perhaps that's not the way to go. Why do you need a class? You could simply have normal functions. If you put them in a module and export them, then they can even be scoped/namespaces with the module name. What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @knittl Yes, I agree that a class of only static methods is not a class. I was collecting reflexive methods in classes supposing that supplying a constructor for such classes wouldn't have made sense. However, jsDoc and this conversation have made me think ... so, thank you!